# Using Google Apps Script to Post JSON Data in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, curl, heroku, google-apps-script

I have the following Google Apps Script:

```
function myFunction() {
   var payload =
   {
     "person": {
    "first_name": "test",
    "last_name": "blah"
    }
   };

  var options =
   {
     "method" : "post",
     "contentType" : "application/json",
     "payload" : payload
   };

   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://myappherokuapp.com/curl_example", options);
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

The app I am posting to is a Rails 5 app. The error I am getting when I run the script is...

```
Request failed for https://myherokuapp.com/curl_example returned code 400
```

...and on heroku this is what I am seeing in the logs...

```
2016-11-09T16:43:37.966300+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/curl_example" host=myherokuapp.com request_id=51c138b5-ed30-4d4b-aa61-b477de875695 fwd="75.143.171.231,107.178.224.13" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=19ms status=400 bytes=179
2016-11-09T16:43:37.960171+00:00 app[web.1]: person=%7Blast_name%3Dblah,+first_name%3Dtest%7D
```

I can run this curl command and successfully post data:

```
curl -X POST -d "person[first_name]=john" -d "person[last_name]=doe" https://myherokuapp.com/curl_example
```

Also here is my controller in Rails...

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_person, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:curl_post_example]
...
  def curl_post_example
    Person.create(person_params)
    render plain: "Thanks for sending a POST request with cURL! Payload: #{request.body.read}"
  end
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stringify the payload if you use the "application/json" content type.
Or omit the content type, then it will be transferred as 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'.

I am not sure what the Rails app expect, but the current request is invalid because it expects a json string.

Comment: Thanks J. That worked. I am going to add my full solution below for posterity.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my full solution, see also [Working with JSON](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external#working_with_json) Doc.

```
function myFunction() {
   var data =
   {
    "person":
     {
      "first_name":"boosy",
      "last_name":"cat"
     }
   };

  var payload = JSON.stringify(data);

  var options =
      {
        "method"  : "POST",
        "payload" : payload,
        "contentType" : "application/json",
        "followRedirects" : true,
        "muteHttpExceptions": true
      };

   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://myherokuapp.com/people", options);
  Logger.log(response);
}
```